# Деление на слоги

Tags: слоги

Как правильно делить на слоги слово *письмо* (*пи-сьмо* согласно закону восходящей звучности, или *пись-мо* по новым правилам)? В разных источниках разная информация. Также и слово *больница*. Как правильно разделить слово,  где есть 2 сонорных согласных?

Comment: Да, ученые у единому мнению не пришли. Поэтому и информация  - разная.

Comment: А где, в каких источниках разная информация? Я не встречала, если только в школьных учебниках прошлых лет, и то для младших классов, там транскрипция облегченная, а в студенческих транскрипциях не видела изменений.

Comment: В ВУЗАХ вроде ВОСХОДЯЩАЯ ЗВУЧНОСТЬ,а в интернете вообще где как написано

Comment: Давно к этому вопросу не обращалась, но, помню, и универе изучали, говорили, что единого верного ответа на вопрос о границе слогов нет,  потом как-то для факультатива материал брала из авантовской энциклопедии  "Русский язык" - там точно были разные взгляды на слогоделение пересказаны. В интернете не искала, не скажу.

Comment: @М_Г Мне кажется, что автор вопроса имел в виду: _Как правильно разделить слово, где (= в котором) два сонорных согласных?_

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Опять правы! Но виноват не я, а запятые, вернее, их отсутствие. :))

Answer (score 6):

Так здесь и не может быть единого подхода. 
Для целей переноса деление на слоги должно учитывать, например, морфемный состав, поэт песенник работает с мелодией (как минимум - с относительной длительностью нот на границе слога), ученый знает, что закон восходящей звучности никто не отменял, а автор школьного учебника скорее всего предложит именно "пись-мо". Не такой, уж, кстати, и новый этот вариант...

Answer (score 4):

А какие новые правила? Я знаю только старые:Закрытые слоги встречаются:
1) в конце фонетического слова: вагон [ва-го́н],
2) в середине слова при стечении двух и более согласных, если
а) после [й'] следует любой другой согласный: война [вай'-на́],
б) после остальных непарных звонких ([л], [л'], [м], [м'], [н], [н'], [р], [р']) следует парный по глухости / звонкости согласный: лампа [ла́м-па].
В остальных случаях стечения согласных слоговая граница проходит перед группой согласных: будка [бу́-тка], весна [в'и-сна́],[п'и-с'мо],[ба - л'н'и -цъ].

Два сонорных тоже отходят к следующему слогу.

Comment: в - парный по глухости-звонкости? тогда: **пор-вать**?

Comment: кстати, будка я перенес бы именно как "буд-ка", а не "бу-дка".

Comment: пор-вать-верно,потому что р-сонорный, он более звучный,слогораздел происходит в месте наибольшего спада звучности, а после Р пошёл спад на шумный.
буд-ка - это для переноса, никто не спорит. Есть деление на фонетические слоги, о чём мы говорим, а есть деление на слоги для переноса - это разные вещи. Но фонетический слог:[бу-тка]-бу-дка, делим по произношению

Comment: > Есть деление на фонетические слоги, о чём мы говорим

Я думал, мы всё-таки говорим о слогах для переноса. Какой практический смысл имеет говорить здесь о делении на фонетические слоги?

Comment: Практический смысл для студентов вузов и колледжей, там это проходится по программе. Теперь ввели и в начальной школе. Там тоже есть задания: разделить слова на слоги и для переноса.Как видите, для переноса даже слогами не называются. Слог - это фонетический слог. Он чаще всего используется в транскрипции, а в школе просто приучают видеть звучность, произносить правильно - делить на слоги, а записывать буквами, не звуками, без транскрипции.

Comment: >Практический смысл для студентов вузов и колледжей, [ТАК КАК] там это проходится по программе

Это как раз сугубо теоретический, а не практический смысл. Если для студента здесь смысл чисто практический - "не получить двойку", в шею такого студента. 

Практический смысл деления на слоги, например, в начальной школе - облегчить процесс обучения чтению. С этой точки зрения важно не разрывать ПИ и не разрывать СЬ, чтобы получить правильное звучание из написанного текста. Полезным также будет стараться видеть морф целиком ("рвать" внутри "по-рвать"). А "восходящая звучность"... ну, вы меня по

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, это слово нужно поделить так: пись-мо. Мягкий знак не отделяется от предыдущей согласной, так что я использую именно это правило. Пожалуй, стоит привести другой пример. Слово *маньяк* переносится так: мань-як. Мягкий знак, как я сказал выше, не отделяется от предыдущей согласной.

Используйте это правило, и тогда Ваш перенос будет правильным.

Comment: Tagirix, речь идёт не о делении на слоги для переноса, а о транскрипции, о фонетическом разборе. Почитайте комментарии вверху

Answer (score 1):

Согласно полному академическому справочнику, пункт 217, возможны оба варианта переноса: **пи-сьмо и пись-мо.**

[**ПРАВИЛА ПЕРЕНОСА** | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)

Тагирик, что касается мягкого знака, то здесь имеется в виду, что нельзя начинать следующий слог с мягкого знака. Как, например , в слове маньяк. Не допускается перенос: ман -ьяк, кол-ьцо, пер-ьями, бул-ьон.